# how to use defined constant in outer module for match operation?

Tags: elixir

I want to use constant as match condition, and the code is as follows:

`Template` module is used the data structure

```
defmodule Mechanics.Disk.Template do
  defstruct [:template_name,:parameter1,:parameter2]
  defmacro const_template_type_a do
    quote do: "a"
  end
end
```

It is used here

```
defmodule Mechanics.User do

  alias Mechanics.Disk.Template, as: Template
  def initialize_local_map(
    %Template{template_name: Template.const_template_type_a,
    parameter1: Parameter1,
    parameter2: Parameter2}) do
  end
end
```

Error message, if it can't be used, I have to use numeric value here directly.

```
[{
    "resource": "/Users/yuchen/Documents/Project/CY2/mechanics/lib/mechanics/User.ex",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "(CompileError) cannot invoke remote function Mechanics.Disk.Template.const_template_type_a/0 inside a match",
    "source": "Elixir",
    "startLineNumber": 42,
    "startColumn": 5,
    "endLineNumber": 42,
    "endColumn": 61
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is probably not the best one, but here is what happens.

To use macros defined in another module, one must explicitly `require` that module. Your code does not `require Template` and hence [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) compiler treats `Template.const_template_type_a` as a remote function call, instead of a call to macro expansion, hence the error. The below would fix the issue.

```elixir
defmodule Mechanics.User do
  alias Mechanics.Disk.Template, as: Template

  require Template   # ← THIS

  def initialize_local_map(
    %Template{template_name: Template.const_template_type_a,
    parameter1: Parameter1,
    parameter2: Parameter2}) do
  end
end
```

---

That said, one cannot call remote functions in matches, but one can perfectly call macros because they are expanded in compile time and the resulting *AST* has no remote calls.